# Center the main Word from D3-WordCloud horizontally

Tags: javascript, d3.js, alignment, center, words

I have the following WordCloud.
The original Code is from Jason Davies D3-JavaScript-WordCloud Example.
https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html

Most of the Code below is from this really helpfull tutorial (in German):
http://www.advitum.de/blog/2012/04/tagcloud-mit-php-und-javascript-erstellen-word-cloud-d3/
Thank You Lars Ebert!

EDIT: Now I have learned a little bit more. I have cleared nonsensical code.

**My goal is to center the first word from array horizontally.**

The first word is now centered horizontally, but now there is a gap in the Cloud.
Just at the x,y point where the word would be without positioning.

**My new question is: How do I remove this gap?**

Thank You.

```
var wordcloud, size = [800, 800]; //Cloud Size
var fillColor = d3.scale.category20b();

function loaded() {
    d3.layout.cloud()
        .size(size) 
        .words(words)
        .font("Impact")
        .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size;})
        .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
        .on("end", draw)
        .start();       
}

function draw(words) {
    wordcloud = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", size[0])
        .attr("height", size[1])
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (size[0]/2) + "," + (size[1]/2) + ")");
    wordcloud.selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return fillColor(d.text.toLowerCase()); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

     //Edit
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        if(i == 0){
            return "translate(" + [0, 0] + ")rotate(" + 0 + ")";    //handle first element
        }else{
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")"; //handle the rest
        }
    })
    //--------------

    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
```

Comment: Could you, by any chance, post the complete html, css and js-combination?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative margin equal to one of the size calculations:

```
 wordcloud.selectAll("text")
     ...
     ...
     ...
     .style("margin-left", function(d) {return d.size + "px"})
```